# How do I define a custom column type that enforces validation in flask-cqlalchemy?

Tags: python, flask, cassandra, flask-cqlalchemy

I am using [flask-cqlalchemy](https://github.com/thegeorgeous/flask-cqlalchemy) to connect to Cassandra in my Flask application. I am defining the Cassandra models by doing something like following:

```py
from flask_cqlalchemy import CQLAlchemy

# app is Flask app
cassandra_db = CQLAlchemy(app)

class CassandraBase(cassandra_db.Model):
    column1 = cassandra_db.columns.DateTime(default=lambda: datetime.now(tz=pytz.UTC))
```

I know that we can define custom user types by inheriting from `cassandra_db.UserType`. I saw following example in the [documentation](https://github.com/thegeorgeous/flask-cqlalchemy).

```py
class Address(cassandra_db.UserType):
    street = cassandra_db.columns.Text()
    zipcode = cassandra_db.columns.Integer()
```

But, I want to define a custom `DateTimeTz` type that enforces users to pass timezone information. Something like following:

```py
class DateTimeTz:
    # if user pass a datetime without timezone info, raise `ValidationError`
    # Also I don't want to specify the column name here
```

So, that I can use `DateTimeTz` in all my Cassandra models like following:

```py
class CassandraBase(cassandra_db.Model):
    column1 = DateTimeTz(default=lambda: datetime.now(tz=pytz.UTC))
```

So far, I have put a validation in the model class itself like following:

```py
class CassandraBase(cassandra_db.Model):
    column1 = cassandra_db.columns.DateTime(default=lambda: datetime.now(tz=pytz.UTC))

    def validate(self):  # Overridden the `validate` method of base `Model` class
        super().validate()

        if self.column1 and not self.column1.tzinfo:
            raise ValidationError('No timezone information passed in column1')
```

But the issue is that in every Cassandra model, I have to write override the `validate` method and include many `if` statements for all such `DateTime` columns that must have timezone information.

I went through the documentation and the many examples I could find on Internet but haven't found anything except above way of overriding the `validate` method to enforce the same unlike what we can do in `flask-sqlalchemy` by using `TypeDecorator` base class like following.

```py
from sqlalchemy.types import TypeDecorator

class DateTimeTZ(TypeDecorator):
    impl = DateTime
    cache_ok = True

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if value is not None and not value.tzinfo:
            raise ValueError("tzinfo is required")
        return value
```

Is there a better approach for doing the same in `flask-cqlalchemy` for Cassandra?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to me to create a custom date-time type that includes timezone information. Doing so makes it cumbersome since you need to parse the value of the column to extract the timezone.

It would be better to simply use a CQL `timestamp` type which is encoded as a 64-bit signed integer that represents the date and time since Unix epoch, 1 January 1970 00:00 GMT. You can then decide to display it in whatever timezone  you want.

By using a `timestamp`, data is in a consistent format and you don't have to implement any validation to store or retrieve data. Cheers!